# Android custom typeface in chinese text

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to change typeface in a Textview which shows a chinese text.

My code is:

```
chinesetext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textChinese);

Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/DFXSM1B.ttf");

chinesetext.setTypeface(tf);
```

DFXSM1B.ttf is in my assets/fonts folder.
I am unable to see the textview typeface changed.

How can I change to a custom typeface in a chinese text ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using paint to set typeface, it dosen't work for chinese text...
I used the font family is `思源宋体 Medium`

and my code like this: (that is very simple)

```
var typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "fonts/font1.otf")
paint.typeface = typeface
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

All the files in `asset` folder must have lower-cased names.

Rename the file in lower case (dfxsm1b.ttf) and it must work.

Comment: Same problem with simkai.ttf... It works when TextView shows an English text, but not with Chinese text